# How to implement file icon overlay in java, the way, e.g., turtoisesvn or dropbox do

Tags: java, windows-7

I am looking for the best (fast and easy to implement, not necessary most robust) way to overlay file icons in Windows 7 Explorer from a prototype written in java. I have seen on SO questions on the icon overlaying in Net and Python, none for java.

Comment: Do you want to add icon overlays to existing software such as explorer or do you want overlays for icons *in your Java application*? The former is not well-suited for Java, as it's a very system-dependent operation.

Comment: There is no generic answer. Which UI framework do you use? Swing, SWT or something else? How do you load the images?

Comment: I would like to overlay icons in Windows 7 Explorer from a java program.

Comment: that will be hard. I suggest doing it in a language that allows more direct interaction with the system.

Comment: @Joachim. I also reach this conclusion. I am now investigating how it can be done in VB or C#. I will create an adapter and use JACOB library to interact with icons through the adapter from Java.

Comment: Setting bounty to see if there is a solution I have missed in my investigations.

Answer (score 6):

I'm affraid this cannot be entirely done in java. You must create and register a COM object that implements the IExtractIcon interface among other things, and associate it with the files you want to manage. [more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thx for the link. It lets me find that I need to implement a Icon Overlay Handler:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look into JNA (https://github.com/twall/jna) - it will allow you to call native code - eg. from user32.dll, etc. - without the burden than JNI would put on you. We're using JNA to get other windows' titles for instance. If you find the information about making icon overlays from native code, you should be able to translate it into JNA quite easly.

Comment: While I endorse JNA in general, it's not likely to fit the bill here.